# How to fix C++ char converting?

Tags: c++

I have a these functions which written in C++ :

```
#include ...

char read_somthing()
{
    int n = 0, spot = 0;
    char buf = '\0';

    char response[13];
    memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

    do {
        n = read( fd, &buf, 1 );
        sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
        spot += n;
    } while( buf != '\r' && n > 0);
    cout << "Response: " << response << endl;
    return buf; 
}

void main()
{
   cout << read_somthing();
   char response = read_somthing();
   cout << response; 
}
```

The problem is, First cout works and prints the true value, but the second one is returning empty line , i think it has something to do with second line in main function, How can i fix it ?

PS : I comment out the `cout << read_somthing();` but nothing appear in output.

Comment: Show what exactly `read_somthing()` is doing.  How does it populate `response`?

Comment: looks OK with what you've provided... maybe << endl at the end of your cout might make it more readable?  or maybe your read_something is broken?  if you just return '*' from read_something does it work?

Comment: You know that you are returning a single character from your `read_something()` function and not some string?

Comment: What is the intention of `read_somthing`?

Comment: Please clean up your code and provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov it read serial port.

Comment: and you want it to return this port?

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov no it just read it and put it in char and then send  it.

Comment: put what into a char? A char is a single character, so I am struggling to understand what are you trying to represent with it

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov read serial port output.it read perfectly and send it perfectly.but i can't use it.

Comment: But a serial port is not a character, it is a string of characters, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `read_somthing` is reading a character in input and returning a copy of that. The second time you call `read_somthing`, the input stream has been moved ahead of 1 character, and if the input is of 1 character, then reading another one will yield no results.

Comment: Yes , i suspect that, commenting out  the first one does not help, still empty output.

Comment: Plus there is a memory leak as no one deletes the return buffer. BTW: The return values of `read_something` differ.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the initialisation and assignment.
in c it is allowed but in c++ it will give different results

The first one relies on initialization while the second one - on assignment. In C++ these operations are over loadable and therefore can potentially lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `buf` variable, which is single character. When `do {} while()` loop exits there's chance `buf` contains `\r` (or junk when `read` failed), which will not be shown on console output.

You probably want to return data gathered in `response`. To mitigate problems with data allocation etc. just use `std::string` - change return type of `read_something` and last line to `return response;`